# flurry integration into (native c++) DirectX wp8 app

Tags: c++, windows-phone-8, native, flurry

Can I integrate Flurry into DirectX (no C# code) WP8 app?
Flurry docs have some instructions, but they are for C# app. I have a FlurryWP8SDK.dll and I don't know is it possible to integrate it into my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless Flurry comes out with a C++ SDK you can't integrate Flurry in a pure Direct3D app. You could however use the Direct3D with XAML app template. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj714079(v=vs.105).aspx

You will still get good Direct3D performance, and will have most of your code in the C++ WinRT component. Having the C# layer will allow you to integrate Flurry, and you can pass down delegate functions from the C# into your WinRT component so that your C++ code can log events with Flurry.

Edit: I wrote a blog post about this topic with some code examples - http://robwirving.com/2014/07/21/calling-c-methods-c-winrt-components/